# How to select one radio button from radiogroup in a RecylcerView in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, radio-button, radio-group

So I want to create this activity where it has 10 question and 5 answers for each question.
Like this - [UI recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ9vr.png)

I want to get what answer user selected for each question, like q01 - 4 and q02 - 2 like wise. I'm new to developing so I have no idea how to? can anyone help me?

This is my adapter classs,

```
public class DailyQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DailyQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 private ArrayList<DailyQuestionModel> questionList;

public DailyQuestionAdapter(ArrayList<DailyQuestionModel> questionList){
    this.questionList = questionList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View questionView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_daily, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(questionView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String question = questionList.get(position).getQuestion();
    holder.questionText.setText(question);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView questionText;
    public RadioGroup answers;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        questionText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.daily_question_textview);
        answers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.daily_answer);

    }
}
```

And this is my Main Class,

```
public class DailyQuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private ArrayList<DailyQuestionModel> questionList;
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_questions);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.daily_question_recycler);
    questionList = new ArrayList<>();

    setQuestion();
    setAdapter();
}

private void setAdapter() {
    DailyQuestionAdapter adapter = new DailyQuestionAdapter(questionList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setQuestion() {
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q01)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q02)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q03)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q04)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q05)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q06)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q07)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q08)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q09)));
    questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(getResources().getString(R.string.q10)));
}
}
```

Thank You in Adavance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface as a listener of radio button click.

```
public interface AnswerSelectedListener {
    void answerSelected(String answer);
}
```

Add an AnswerSelectedListener class attribute to your DailyQuestionModel class and constructor & Pass an implementation of this interface to each of your DailyQuestionModel:

```
questionList.add(new DailyQuestionModel(
    getResources().getString(R.string.q01),
    new AnswerSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void answerSelected(String answer) {
            //Here you have the selected answer to question 01
        }
    })
)
```

Inside you RecyclerView adapter, call this listener when an answer is selected:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final DailyQuestionModel model = questionList.get(position);
    String question = model.getQuestion();
    holder.questionText.setText(question);
    answers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
            if (isChecked) {
                model.answerListener.answerSelected(checkedRadioButton.getText()))
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code is not tested but I think it gives the overall flow.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much I was stuck in it!